# An instructor has an exam of 5 questions and a question bank of 50 questions. Are there $50\choose 5$ or $(50)_5$ possible exams?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Where $(50)_5 = 50! / 45! $ and $50\choose 5$ $= 50!/(5!45!)$

I've narrowed it down to these two possibilities (though even these may be wrong), but I think I'm confusing myself as to which one I use. Can anyone suggest a good way of thinking of this problem that will make it apparent whether I need use use the falling factorial or the binary coefficient?

Edit: thank you for all the answers! Indeed, I meant $50!/45$ as the falling factorial. Also, the question doesn't specify whether it was meant to be ordered or unordered, but I think I understand my confusion now!

Comment: 50 choices for the first, 49 for the second...

Comment: $(50)_5$, the pochhammer symbol, is in reference to the falling factorial and should be equal to $50!/(50-5)!$ not $50!/5!$

Comment: It depends on whether you consider two exams with the same 5 questions [but in different orders] as two distinct exams or the same exam.

Comment: Now... as for your actual question once that mistake is addressed... we have to ask how you decide whether one exam is the "same" or "different" than another?  Do you require that the questions all be the same and appear in the same order?  Or if you have the same questions appearing but in a different order would they still be considered the same or would they be considered different?

Comment: @Randall Indeed, that was a typo, thank you!

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you! It seems that my confusion stemmed from the question not making it clear whether we're dealing with something ordered or unordered. My understanding is much more firm now; thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate and emphasize, this entirely matters on what you consider as being considered "different" versus "the same."  And, in the long run, it is possible that such a distinction doesn't even matter in the first place!

Suppose we were asking this question in order to solve the probability question of "A student had time to study $30$ out of $50$ possible exam questions.  If the exam contains five randomly selected exam questions from those $50$, what is the probability that the student had studied each of those questions?"

I must emphasize, we have a *choice* of what sample space to use to describe this problem.  There are many different sample spaces that we could have chosen to describe this, and whichever we choose is entirely up to us!  There are certain benefits to choosing certain sample spaces though compared to others.  In particular, some things to look out for are making sure the events we are interested in calculating the probability of are valid events in our sample space, simplicity of the sample space, and whether or not the sample space is such that each outcome in it is equally likely to occur.  After all, we may only use counting techniques to find probability by setting $Pr(A)=\frac{|A|}{|S|}$ in equiprobable sample spaces.

---

In solving the above question with the sample space being that we treat the order that the questions appear as relevant, we would have $30\cdot 29\cdot 28\cdot 27\cdot 26$ possible exams where our student studied every question out of $50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46$ possible exams.

In solving the above question with the sample space being that we treated the order that the questions appear in as not relevant, we would have $\binom{30}{5}$ possible exams where our student studied every question out of $\binom{50}{5}$ possible exams.

Taking the ratio in each case gives us the probability.  Notice that

$$\dfrac{30\cdot 29\cdot 28\cdot 27\cdot 26}{50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46} = \dfrac{\binom{30}{5}}{\binom{50}{5}}$$

and so it did not matter which interpretation we used for this as both approaches led to the same answer.  Of course, if we were to then ask "What is the probability that the first question on the test was one that the student studied" then the sample space where order does not matter cannot be the one that we use as it did not keep information about which spot in the exam was occupied by which question.  But, then again, we aren't restricted to using the first sample space either and we could have considered the sample space which only kept track of which question was the first question, giving an answer of $\dfrac{30}{50}$, which is simpler than using the first which would have given an equal but more tiresome answer of $\dfrac{30\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46}{50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46}$.

Comment: Immense thanks for this detailed response! I'm learning about discrete probability as well so this is amazingly helpful and unifying for me! One question about the problem you described: do we not have to take into account the fact that the student only studied $30$ of the possible $50$ questions (i.e. $50\choose30$) anywhere?

Comment: The solution makes complete sense, but it also feels like $50\choose30$ is a piece of information that goes unaddressed in the solution. But maybe I'm thinking about this incorrectly. Thank you again for all the help!

Comment: You could have kept track of that in the sample space as well in which case it would have appeared in both the numerator and denominator and subsequently cancelled each other out.  We could also have kept track of what he ate for breakfast.  It didn't really matter which he chose to study as there is no bias in regards to what he picked vs what appeared, so we opt to use the simpler space

Comment: The fact that the student studies 30 questions instead of, say, 47 is addressed in the numerator of each.  The point is we don't actually care *which* 30 they were

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense and clears up any doubts I had. Thank you very much for the help, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This depends.

If the order of the question matters (i.e. if two exams with the 5 same questions but in another order are considered different), there are $50.49.48.47.46$ possibilities.

If the order of the questions does not matter, it is $\binom{50}{5}$.

Comment: That was simpler than I thought, thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If the order of questions on the test does not matter, the answer is $$\binom {50}{5}= \frac {50!}{5!45!}=2118760$$

Otherwise we have $$ \frac {50!}{45!}=254251200$$ many tests.

Comment: Who said that the order of the questions on the test doesn't matter?  That is one possible interpretation, but not the only interpretation.  This hasn't been clarified.  A test where the hardest question appears first might stress a student out and prevent the student from reaching the rest of the questions in time while a test where the hardest question appears last might relax the student, allowing him to answer the first several before getting stuck.  Getting a score of 0/5 compared to a score of 4/5 is a very different outcome.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thanks for the comment. I have fixed my answer to adress both cases.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I guess I was confused because the question doesn't make clear which of the two it's asking for